# How to show checkbox 'checked state' in edit.html.erb

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, checkbox

I have checkboxes in my rails app. In filling forms, a checkbox changes color to blue when it is checked. After the form is submitted and the User tries to edit/update the form, the checkbox 'checked color(blue)' does not show even though it is checked. This makes it difficult for the user to update or edit the checkboxes.

What i want is for the user to see in edit.html.erb the checked(blue color) state of the checkboxes that was chosen when the form/record was initially created.
This is a sample of my checkbox code in new.html.erb

```
<% Perk.all.each do |perk| %>
  <input type="checkbox", class="hidden" value="<%= perk.id %>" 
  name="company[perk_ids][]" id="company_perk_ids_<%= perk.id %>"/>
  <label class="category-choice" for="company_perk_ids_<%= perk.id %>">
<% end %>
```

This is my js file

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".category-choice").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
      });
    });
```

In my css, i have

```
 .category-choice {
  background: #CFCFD3;
  padding: 27px 15px 24px 10px;

  &.active {
    background: #51ADCF;
  }
}
```

In my edit.html.erb the sample code for the checkbox is the same as the one in new.html.erb

```
<% Perk.all.each do |perk| %>
 <input type="checkbox", class="hidden" value="<%= perk.id %>" 
 name="company[perk_ids][]" id="company_perk_ids_<%= perk.id %>"/>
 <label class="category-choice" for="company_perk_ids_<%= perk.id %>">
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a TurboLinks issue. Does changing your JS to this work?

```
(function() {
  $(document).on("turbolinks:load", function() {
    $(".category-choice").click(function(){
      $(this).toggleClass("active");
    });
  });
}).call(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

On dom ready you may test if the element is checked. Hence, according to that you may [.toggleClass(function, [state])](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/#toggleClass-function-state).

The snippet:

```js
$("[id^='job_perk_ids_']").on('change', function (e) {
    $("[id^='job_perk_ids_']").not(this).removeAttr('checked');
    $('label[for!=' + this.id + ']').removeClass('active');
    var lbl = $('label[for=' + this.id + ']');
    var isChk = $(this).is(":checked");
    lbl.toggleClass(function(idx, className) {
        return "active";
    }, isChk);
});

// at dom ready
$(".category-choice").toggleClass(function(idx, className) {
    var inpt = '#' + $(this).attr('for');
    return $(inpt).is(":checked") ? "active" : "";
});
```

```css
.category-choice {
    background: #cfcfd3;
    padding: 27px 15px 24px 10px;
}

.category-choice.active {
    background: #51adcf;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
    <input type="checkbox" class="hidden" value="perk.id" checked name="job[perk_ids][]"
           id="job_perk_ids_id0"/>
    <label class="category-choice" for="job_perk_ids_id0">my label0: checked</label>
    <input type="checkbox"  class="hidden" value="perk.id"  name="job[perk_ids][]"
           id="job_perk_ids_id1"/>
    <label class="category-choice" for="job_perk_ids_id1">my label1</label>
</form>
```

Comment: the solution does not work. When i add checked' to the 'name' of the checkboxes, it checks all check boxes. Which is not what i want. I want only checked items to be affected by '.active'

Comment: I dont think you fully understood my question so I decided to update it

Comment: @HakeemBaba After you submit the form a new page, I assume, is sent back. On this page you can set the color of the checked elements to active. Where the active class can contain the color blue. I'm sorry, but I cannot understand the flow: client --> server --> client.

Comment: yhh, so i would like to know how i can set the color of the checked elements to 'active' on the edit page?

Comment: @HakeemBaba in order to handle the **on the edit page** event is enough to substitute my change event listener with yours. In this case I don't know anything about your **on the edit page** event.